# How can I check whether if current_user liked this or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails3,devise and acts_as_votable

I prepared the view to show 'bookmark' or 'un-bookmark' depending on his voting situation.
But I have no idea what to put. Anyone has idea?

```
<% if xxxxxxxxxxxx %> <= *when @community hasn't been voted by current_user*              
  <%= link_to t('.bookmark', :default => t("helpers.links.bookmark")),
              bookmark_community_path(@community), :class => 'btn' %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to t('.unbookmark', :default => t("helpers.links.unbookmark")),
              bookmark_community_path(@community), :class => 'btn-danger' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
current_user.voted_for? @community
```

**upd**: Example from documentation https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter

```
@user.likes @comment1

@user.voted_for? @comment1 # => true
```

Comment: Thanks for reply:) what if I like to use 'like' instead of vote??

Comment: `voted_for?` works for likes too. I've added example from documentation